# Spring Batch custom completion policy

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to move from a commit interval to a custom completion policy.

My chunk tag is defined below.

`<batch:chunk reader="x" writer="y" processor="z" skip-limit="100" chunk-completion-policy="myPolicy">`
     `<batch:stream...>`
`</batch:chunk>`

`<bean id="myPolicy" class="com.example.MyPolicy"/>`

MyPolicy extends SimpleCompletionPolicy and implements CompletionPolicy.  In the constructor of MyPolicy, if I add super(10) I expected to see the chunk size get set to 10.  But when running the batch job this class is not recognized and the chunk size is set to 1.  If I put printlns in the isComplete method nothing will be written out which leads me to believe I've configured my custom policy incorrectly.

Could someone please let me know if I missed a step in configuring a custom policy?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody in community can help me configure a custom completion policy :( ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of spring batch older than 2.2.2, then it's known a bug; see [Spring Batch - late binding of commit interval not working with skip policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066053/spring-batch-late-binding-of-commit-interval-not-working-with-skip-policy)